# CodeIgniter - Calling a function from inside a view

Tags: codeigniter

Is it possible to call a function which is located in a controller from a view?

This is what i have in my controller, as an example

```
function checkKeyExists($userid, $key){
}
```

Then inside my view i have the following

```
if(checkKeyExists($row->id, $role->key)){
}
```

But when I run it, it says that checkKeyExists is not defined.

If anyone can let me know how I could do this, that would be great.

Comment: More than one year has passed and you still didn't accept an answer...

Comment: 9 years in the future I AM HERE! And this question is still open :-/

Answer (score 13):

Views are not meant to call controller actions.
Reverse your logic, call that function in the controller and set it to a variable you sent to the view. Then you can have the if statement check that variable in your view template.

If that doesn't work for you, maybe a helper is what you need: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: The code that is inside the view, is also in a foreach loop and gets the variables dynamically, so i cant run it as the page is being rendered ... Does this mean i have to make it a helper? and can you call a model from a helper

Comment: Why would you want to call a model from a helper ? You could call the model from your view and have checkKeyExists() method in your model, but that is not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

Like Widox said, I think a Helper is the best way out.
Something like this:

```
<?php // test_helper.php
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function checkKeyExists($userid, $key, $table)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $query = $CI->db->query("SELECT $keyFROM $table WHERE id = $userid LIMIT 1");
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false; 
    }
}

?>
```

Then you can freely use on your views, just loading in your respective controllers like: $this->load->helper('test');.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller should pass a set of data to your view.

Your view can then test if something is set and then act accordingly.

```
$this->data['my_setting']='value';
$this->load->vars($this->data);
$this->load->view('your_view');
```

Then in your view:

```
if(isset($my_setting)){
  do something with my_setting
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can declare a function this way inside views:

```
$myfunction = function_that_do_something( ) {
}

// then call as you want
$myfunction( );
```

the only thing is that you cannot acces the variables from the function -> simply pass them to the function

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
public function xyz(){
   $data['controller'] = $this;
   $this->load->view('your_view_file',$data);
}
```

View:

```
$controller->xyz();
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling a controller function from view is not a good idea. it against the MVC role. But you can call the Model function from view. More answers about this question is vailable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986520/how-to-call-codeigniter-controller-function-from-view)

Answer (score -1):

This way is smooth.

```
@controller method
$obj = array();
$obj['fnc'] = function(){ return 'hello'; };
$this->load->view( 'your_path', $obj );

@view
echo $fnc();
```

Comment: Keep in mind, function is out of the controller scope, so use $CI =& get_instance() instead of $this