# codeigniter unable to call function in the controller want to use in the view file

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

```
public function test() {
    echo 'helloooo';
}
```

this is the `controllers/ajax.php`

i want to call this function in

```
views/paymentresponce.php
```

i tried `Ajax::test();`

how to call it in the this payment responce

it gives me the error as

```
Fatal error: Class 'Ajax' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\handysites\admin\application\views\clienth\paymentrespone.php on line 8
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calling a Controller function from a view is against the principles of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Views are only for presenting data that is HTML output.

You can call the function in your controller and pass the data to the view.

Answer (score 0):

in views you cannot call controller functions. if you are working with ajax you can call your controller function by url

```
yoursite.com/controller/function
```

you can pass controller instance for calling function like

```
public function test() {
  $object['controller']=$this; 
  $this->load->view('test',$object);
}
```

View:

```
$controller->test();
```

For more :- [How to call codeigniter controller function from view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986520/how-to-call-codeigniter-controller-function-from-view)

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be `Ajax::test();`

It should be `Ajax->test();`

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you call a controller method in CodeIgniter.

You should have something like this for calling a method:

```
yourController->test(); ?>
```

In this case, it's:

```
ajax->test();
```

If you are accessing this method by clicking a link in your view page, then write like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/ajax/test">Drink up me hearties, Yo ho!</a>
```