# I need to call a controller function inside a view -Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to call a function from view to echo a value. I use following code,

Controller (test_controller)

```
public function displayCategory()
    {
        $this->load->model('Model_test');

        $data['categories'] = $this->Model_test->getCategories();

        $this->load->view('test_view', $data);
    }

public function display($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('Model_test');
        $name= $this->Model_test->getName($id);
        return $name;
    }
```

Model (Model_test)

```
function getCategories() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM category");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

function getName($userId) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM user where id = '$userId' ");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row()->name;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

View

```
<div id="body">

        <?php                
            foreach ($categories as $object) {
                $temp = $this->test_controller->display($object->id);
                echo $object->title . "&nbsp;&nbsp;". $object->no . $temp . '<br/>';
            }
        ?>

</div>
```

but some error when running the code.

error Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$test_controller in view

Comment: Show us how you get `$categories` array.

Comment: @Kyslik edited.. i added code inside function displayCategory()

Comment: ok, now show contents of `getCategories()` you want to use join or perhaps prepare data inside that function... so you dont have to do "data manipulation" inside views...

Comment: @Kyslik added inside model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you use CodeIgniter 2 or 3.

Anyway, basically you don't want to use anything inside View files except perhaps helper function(s) or some kind of "presenter" layer (that should be called inside controller I guess).

---

### Solution using Join

Go and read this manual [page](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) and search for join. There you can learn about implementation of [SQL join directive](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

You want to modify this (`getCategories()`) function so it returns data that you require

```
function getCategories() {

   $this->db->select('category.title, category.no, user.name as username')
            ->from('category')
            ->join('user', 'user.id = category.id');
   $query = $this->db->get();

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
       return $query->result();
   } else {
       return NULL;
   }
}
```

and in view you can get your **username** like this

```
foreach ($categories as $object) {
    echo $object->title . "&nbsp;&nbsp;". $object->no . $object->username . '<br/>';
}
```

> I am not 100% sure so please post comments I will edit this answer later.

---

### Solution "breaking rules"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24320884/1564365

---

#### general notes

Also consider naming your tables using plural so *categories*, *users*...

Also it is a bad practise to use "category.id as user.id" (storing user id inside category table in "id" field) instead you shold use either a pivot table or in case of 1:1 relation field "user_id".