# Accessing controller's function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter framework to develop a website. I am currently working on `home.php` view under the view folder. I need to use `UserInfo()` function which is inside one of the controllers. Any suggestion how to access that function?

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

            public function UserInfo(){

            $this->load->model('model_user');                
            $data['title'] = 'Users';              
            $data['users'] = $this->model_user->getUser();              
            $this->load->view('template/users', $data);
        }
}
```

Comment: Paste also your model code !!

Comment: In the question, choose `Edit` and add the code for the user model

Comment: Added the model_user.

Comment: if you want to get user details in your current controller function simply include the user model in your controller function and get user record. You cannot call controller method inside another controller.

Comment: Edited the question and clarified ... Any suggestions on why I can not access `$users`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986520/how-to-call-codeigniter-controller-function-from-view?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You **cant call controller method inside another controller**. Its No Way to do it.

You have two way to resolve this issue

1. If you want to access the function which place inside the
   controller, add that into an model. So by loading model you can call
   it.
2. use `redirect('welcome/UserInfo')` if you just need to call the function

Comment: Abdulla, I am not trying to call a controller method inside another controller. I am now in `home.php` view where I have a table to show my data, need the function UserIfo() to do that. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, I have a table called "users". I have a `model_user` where it connects to the users table and fetch users data. Now I want to show that data in the `home.php` view.

Comment: what about this `$this->load->view('home', $data);`

Comment: Show me the complete code. I can't get an idea on this. So i can help you

Comment: Abdulla, I tried editing the code in the question to help you better what exactly I am doing. Complete code is above.

Answer (score 0):

As You want to call controller function in other controller.In `codeigniter` `App` folder `core` folder exists you make a custom core `controller` and all other controllers extend with your custom controller

In your Custom Core controller

```
class CustomCore extends CI_Controller
{
     /* ---YOUR FUNCTION IN CUSTOMCORE---- */

      public function mycorefunc()
      {
           //Do something
      }

}
```

and your all other controllers extend with custom core

```
class YourController extends Customcore
{

      function controllerfunction()
      {
            $this->mycorefunc();// Call corefunction 
      }

}
```