# WP functions style in codeIgniter

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

Where should I put the function that loads a model and Display a view but that is not accessible from the URL. I mean, I need to write a function that should call from the view and this function displays a menu list.

```
function displayMenu () {
   $menu = $this->model->getMenuResults();
   $this->load->view( 'ViewResults', $menu);
}
```

Should I write this as a private function in the main controller?

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357225/codeigniter-calling-a-function-from-inside-a-view)

Comment: You should write a function in controller, which send menu data to the view and display that menu accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use private functions in codeigniter controller

```
private function _displayMenu()
{
  $menu = $this->model->getMenuResults();
  $this->load->view( 'ViewResults', $menu);
}
```

Straight from documentation

**Private Functions**

In some cases you may want certain functions hidden from public access. To make a function private, simply add an underscore as the name prefix and it will not be served via a URL request. For example, if you were to have a function like this:

```
private function _utility()
{
  // some code
}
```

Trying to access it via the URL, like this, will not work:

```
example.com/index.php/blog/_utility/
```

For more details go to [**http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#private**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#private)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in one of your helper functions like this

```
function displayMenu () {
   $CI = &get_instance();
   //choose whichever is appropriate
   //option 1
   //if your model is globally loaded then simply call the model like this
   //$menu = $CI->loadedmodel->getMenuResults();
   // option 2 otherwise load the model here
   //$CI->load->model('model_name'); 
   //$menu = $CI->model_name->getMenuResults();


   $CI->load->view( 'ViewResults', $menu);
}
```